# Display sibling categories in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, siblings

On my WooCommerce website, I have the following Product categories:

```html
• Clothing
  - Tee shirts
  - Jeans
  - Shirts

• Food
  - Bread
  - Cheese
  - Butter
```

On the category page for "Butter" I would like to show the name of the parent category and the sibling categories of the category "Butter". This would look like this:

```
<h2>Food</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Bread</li>
   <li>Butter</li>
   <li>Cheese</li>
</ul>
```

Similarly, the category page for Jeans should show:

```
<h2>Clothing</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Jeans</li>
   <li>Shirts</li>
   <li>Tee Shirts</li>
</ul>
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a first guess, but I think you could grab the category from the query vars, get the term object, and use the term's parent ID to create a list of terms:

```
$query_var = get_query_var( 'product_cat', '' );
$term  = get_term_by( 'slug', $product_cat, 'product_cat' );
if( $term->parent_id > 0 ){
    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'child_of' => $term->parent_id );
    wp_list_categories( $args );
}
```

if `wp_list_categories()` doesn't quite output what you'd want, you can always use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and run your own `foreach()` loop.